# facebook Stream Post URL Security Migration

Tags: facebook, post, stream, migration, feed

can someone explain me about this migration? https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/secure_stream_urls_migration/

> all links in stream posts must go to the app's Canvas or Website URL.

app's Canvas is url of my site or url like: https://apps.facebook.com/myApp/

from today I can't post links like https_://apps.facebook.com/myApp/ from several apps, external links works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable or disable **secure stream urls migration** at your app advanced setting:
[image]

Let me show you example about the different "**before enable**" and "**after enable**":

**Before enable:**

Assume you are the **Youtube app** maintainer, user can share the video link (The **link=** parameter) via https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=87741124305&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DOggfnGxAJs0%26feature%3Dshare&display=popup&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Ffacebook_redirect:

[image]

**After enabled:**

If you enabled the setting, you would get error message instead:

[image]

However, user still can share:

- If you doesn't put **link=** parameter:

[image]

- If you put the "link=CANVAS_URL":

[image]